# Как позиционировать balloon в yandex map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При разрешении 320px балун размещается с низу карты, при разрешении больше 320 в центре, можно ли как-то принудительно позиционировать балун с низу на всех мобильных устройствах?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За ширину карты, при которой балун отображается в виде панели отвечает опция **panelMaxMapArea**.

Если вам нужно подобрать ширину больше 320, явно это и укажите. Если балун нужно отображать всегда в виде панели задайте его как **Infinity**. Это есть в [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.panelMaxMapArea).
В скрипте это может выглядеть, например так:

```
myMap.options.set({balloonPanelMaxMapArea:'Infinity'});
```